# Netsuite: How to best make an inventory item virtual?

Tags: netsuite

I have an online store where ~90% of what we sell is real, but ~10% is virtual. (software, training licenses)

Currently in our system all items are coded as "Inventory Item" because operationally on the back end there are benefits. (not sure exactly what)

Because they are inventory items, they show as out of stock and they require shipping, even though they are virtual.

Do I need to just add a custom field called "IsVirtual" and note which products are virtual explicitly, or is there a built-in mechanism for handling virtual products?

Comment: Non physical products such as software and licenses must be made non inventory,  I don't understand the benefits of making them inventory

Comment: Yeah, I just sent a note to my operations team to find out the thinking behind making them inventory items in the first place. I presume there's a perceived benefit, but let me figure out exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to add those items in Netsuite as non inventory.

If you really want to keep them inventory and do not show shipping and out of stock, you got to write a SSP. Based on item attributes returned from search you can modify your code on front end to show/hide shipping and out of stock notice. Additionally when the order is created in your ssp add a logic to add dummy or a free shipping item and also a logic to add inventory.

Comment: We've already sold them as inventory items. There's no way to convert them to non-inventory once we've sold them, is there?

Comment: that's correct. I normally rename them (x-old item name) and make them inactive.

Comment: You need to create SSP to simulate the front end experience as non-inventory item and in backend you complete the invenotry items formalities

Comment: So I've been looking into this, and I don't see how creating items as non-inventory solves any of my problems. It still asks for a shipping address and it still charges shipping for non-inventory items, so how does creating these as non-inventory items improve the situation?

Answer (score 0):

You should make them non-inventory items for sale (unless you are reselling them).

However if you can't do that you do not need to create an SSP. All you need to do is alter the out-of-stock behavior for the item on the item setup page. You may need to tweak your item display template but you shouldn't need to unless you were already displaying stock levels on the buy page.

Comment: We've already sold them as inventory items. There's no way to convert them to non-inventory once we've sold them, is there?

Comment: And yes, in most cases we are reselling them. (in some they are ours) What should they be if we are reselling them?

Comment: that's correct. I normally rename them (x-old item name) and make them inactive.
So if you are reselling them then Non-Inventory Item for Resale otherwise if you produce them in house "Non-Inventory Item For Sale"

Comment: So I've been looking into this, and I don't see how creating items as non-inventory solves any of my problems. It still asks for a shipping address and it still charges shipping for non-inventory items, so how does creating these as non-inventory items improve the situation?

Comment: I'm not sure you can suppress the shipping address since that is asked for tax reasons.  When you create your new items you can uncheck "can be fulfilled/received" which solves some of your issues. That may fix your shipping issues but I think I've had to create shipping rules where a free shipping item is selected when the order weight is = 0. This means you have to enter weights for all shippable items and then when you only have a weightless item in the carat your weightless free item shipping method comes into play.